# Remove hunks relative to a specific path from a patch

Tags: diff, patch

I have a very big patch and I want to remove from it all the hunks relative to a certain path.
For example, consider the following patch:

```
diff -ru a/foo/1.txt b/foo/1.txt
--- a/foo/1.txt 2017-07-19 11:26:26.603140163 +0200
+++ b/foo/1.txt 2017-07-19 11:27:15.499145952 +0200
@@ -1 +1 @@
-1111
+11111
diff -ru a/foo/bar/3.txt b/foo/bar/3.txt
--- a/foo/bar/3.txt 2017-07-19 11:26:51.771143040 +0200
+++ b/foo/bar/3.txt 2017-07-19 11:27:23.419146966 +0200
@@ -1 +1 @@
-3333
+33333
diff -ru a/foo/bar/test/4.txt b/foo/bar/test/4.txt
--- a/foo/bar/test/4.txt    2017-07-19 11:29:38.599167147 +0200
+++ b/foo/bar/test/4.txt    2017-07-19 11:29:43.655167998 +0200
@@ -1 +1 @@
-4444
+44444
```

I would like to remove from the patch all the changes relative to the path `foo/bar`, so that it would become:

```
diff -ru a/foo/1.txt b/foo/1.txt
--- a/foo/1.txt 2017-07-19 11:26:26.603140163 +0200
+++ b/foo/1.txt 2017-07-19 11:27:15.499145952 +0200
@@ -1 +1 @@
-1111
+11111
```

Is there any way I can use `diff`, `patch`, `quilt` or any other tool to do that?

Answer (score 0):

[filterdiff](https://linux.die.net/man/1/filterdiff) it the definitive tool!

`filterdiff -p1 -x foo/bar/* my.patch`